# remove -1 values from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I would like to turn a list which looks like this one:

```
{{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, 2, 3}, {-1, -1, 2}, {2, 3, 4}}
```

into one which looks like that one:

```
{{}, {2, 3}, {2}, {2, 3, 4}}
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: list /. -1 -> Nothing

Answer (score 14):

This :

```
data = {{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, 2, 3}, {-1, -1, 2}, {2, 3, 4}};
DeleteCases[data, -1, Infinity]
```

Addressing @Sjoerd's comment, if the list is 2 dimensional one can adjust the level to 2.

```
data2 = {{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, 2, 3, Exp[-1]}, {-1, -1, 2}, {2, 3, 4}};
DeleteCases[data2, -1, 2]
(* {{}, {2, 3, 1/E}, {2}, {2, 3, 4}} *)
```

Comment: Goes wrong if the data contains elements such as `Exp[-1]`. Only @Mr.Wizard's solution works there.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Good point, thanks, would my edit fix this ?

Comment: It does for two dimensional lists, and it looks like the OP is assuming that.

Answer (score 13):

Replacing -1 with an empty `Sequence` should do it:

```
lst = {{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, 2, 3}, {-1, -1, 2}, {2, 3, 4}};

(* In *)
lst /. {-1 -> Sequence[]}
(* Out *)
{{}, {2, 3}, {2}, {2, 3, 4}}
```

If there are expressions containing `-1` that shouldn't be replaced, and your list is always of depth 2, you can use `Replace` instead of `ReplaceAll`:

```
lst = {{Exp[-1], -1, -1}, {-1, 2, 3}, {-1, -1, 2}, {2, 3, 4}};

Replace[lst, {-1 -> Sequence[]}, {2}]
```

Comparing this solution with [the `DeleteCases` solution from b.gatessucks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16162), it seems the `DeleteCases` solution is faster:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Do[lst /. {-1 -> Sequence[]}, {100000}]] // First
(* Out *)
0.763795

AbsoluteTiming[Do[DeleteCases[lst, -1, Infinity], {100000}]] // First
(* Out *)
0.448700
```

Some other alternatives based on the answer by yulinlinyu (and comments):

```
AbsoluteTiming[Do[Select[#, FreeQ[#, -1] &] & /@ lst, {100000}]] // First
(* Out *)
2.153360

AbsoluteTiming[Do[Cases[#, Except[-1]] & /@ lst, {100000}]] // First
(* Out *)
1.045021
```

If the actual `lst` is larger, the tests may come out differently, but I would suspect not.

Comment: It is really fast!

Comment: Goes wrong if the data contains elements such as `Exp[-1]`. Only Mr.Wizard's solution works there.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: You are right. I added an alternative way using Replace covering this.

Answer (score 2):

If your (ragged) array is entirely numeric, and your desired operation is to remove all negative values, you could use this:

```
Pick[#, UnitStep@#, 1] & @ {{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, 2, 3}, {-1, -1, 2}, {2, 3, 4}}
```

> ```
> {{}, {2, 3}, {2}, {2, 3, 4}}
> ```

This should prove competitively fast as well.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
Select[#, Positive] & /@ {{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, 2, 3}, {-1, -1, 2}, {2, 
   3, 4}}
```

Edit 1:

```
 According to Lenz's and Kguler's advice, the code can be

Select[#, FreeQ[#,-1]&] & /@ {{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, 2, 3}, {-1, -1, 2}, {2, 
       3, 4}}
```

Or

```
    Select[#, #!=-1&] & /@ {{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, 2, 3}, {-1, -1, 
   2}, {2, 3, 4}}
```

Edit 2:

```
 According to the op's comment below, the codes can be something like this:

 Select[#, FreeQ[#,-1]&] & /@ {{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, 2, 3}, {-1, -1, 2}, {2, 
           3, 4}}/.{}->{0,0}
```

Comment: This would also remove elements of other negative numbers, which the title of the question indicates is not the wanted scenario.

Comment: thank you for the nice answers. If the result of a sublist is {} it should be turned into {0,0}. How can I do this?

Comment: You could add this as a requirement to the original question. Replacing empty lists with ReplaceAll should be a good way though.

Comment: maybe `FreeQ[#, -1] &` instead of `Positive`?

Answer (score 1):

Translation of python.

```
Table[If[j != -1, j, ## &[]], {i, list}, {j, i}]
```

```
 [[j for j in i if j != -1] for i in list]
```

A recursive version:

```
foo[L_] := Table[If[ListQ[i], foo[i], If[i != -1, i, ## &[]]], {i, L}];
foo[list]
```