# How to use Select to exclude a single element which I can control?

Tags: filtering

I have code which inserts an expression into lists that I need to remove. I can insert anything I want, a string, variable, or number, into the lists. Suppose I insert the number 13 as my blacklisted element and have a list like

```
l={12, 14 y, 13, 13 x, 13 x -y}
```

I then implement

```
Select[l, # != 13 &]
```

but the output is

```
12
```

My desired output in this case would have been

```
{12, 14 y, 13 x, 13 x -y}
```

I've created a working solution that doesn't feel as elegant as it could be, with now a string blacklist element "13"

```
Select[{12, 14 y, "13", 13 x, 13 x - y}, Not@StringMatchQ[ToString[#], "13"] &]
```

which gives the desired output. Is it possible to refine the original attempt at a solution to work a bit more simply?

Comment: `Select[l, !MatchQ[#, 13] &]
]` is what you're looking for... Your own approach can be modified by using `UnsameQ` or `=!=` instead of `!=` which won't evaluate.

Comment: `Select[l, # =!= 13 &]` works.

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but the closest I can find is [Evaluating an If condition to yield True/False](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8796) which explains that `==` can remain unevaluated while `===` will always evaluate.

Comment: Thanks, man =!= instead of != (which surprisingly has an <esc ! = esc> nice not-equal look to it). It's the little things sometimes.

Comment: That post is actually quite illuminating, thanks

Comment: So is != akin to == in the same way as =!= is to ===?

Comment: @Steve Yes it is

Comment: `Cases[l, Except[13]]` (or "13" is you make it a string)

Comment: I am closing this question.  The direct application of `DeleteCases` is "easily found in the documentation" leaving the nontrivial aspect the behavior of `Unequal`, which is largely covered in R.M's referenced answer.  I shall also add links to some related questions.

Comment: **Related:** [(1290)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1290/121), [(16161)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16161/121), [(22907)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22907/121), and conversely: [(15907)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15907/121), [(38851)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38851/121)

Answer (score 2):

More straigthforward than looking for elements that do not match criteria would be to delete those that match them:

```
l = {12, 14 y, 13, 13 x, 13 x -y} ; 

DeleteCases[l, 13]
DeleteCases[l, 13 | 14 y]
```

> ```
> {12, 14 y, 13 x, 12 x - y}
>
> {12, 13 x, 12 x - y}
> ```

Am I correct or have I missed the point again? ;P

Comment: forests and trees! this is by far the most obvious way to do it